#  Switching between different version of rails in same gem set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed two different version of rails in same gem set. When I do gem list rails it will show as follows:

```
      **rails (3.0.11, 2.3.8)** // This means I have two rails
```

When I create new rails application it will take latest one, that means app should be created using **rails new app_name** not using **rails app_name**.

But I want to use rails 2.3.8 instead of 3.0.11. I know that using RVM helps in switching between different version of rails but they are installed in different gem  set. Is there any possibility to switch between different rails version in same gem set?

Thank you.

Comment: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=13971 Seems to be related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The later version has higher precedence. You have to be explicit when create app by:

`rails _3.0.11_ new my_app`

OR

`rails _2.3.8_ my_app`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are not using Bundler if you are trying to use 2.3.8, so check your config/enrvironment.rb file and change the RAILS_GEM_VERSION to '2.3.8'